# How i can get the facebook fanpage or place rating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

i tried to get rating by facebook graph , but i can get only my fanpage , i need to get the other fanpage .
i understand the facebook api not permitted to get rating from other fanpage or place.
Have any other way to get the rating ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/ratings

> A page access token is required to retrieve this data.

You can only get a Page Token for your own Pages, so it´s not possible to get ratings for other Pages.